# What is auto escape used for in Swig templating for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm trying to write an itinerary app built on Express. Swig is the template engine. I'm confused by Swig's autoescape feature. What exactly does it do?

Swig [documentation](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#autoescape) example:

```
"Control auto-escaping of variable output from within your templates."

// myvar = '<foo>';
{% autoescape true %}{{ myvar }}{% endautoescape %}
// => <foo>
{% autoescape false %}{{ myvar }}{% endautoescape %}
// => <foo>
```

My code:

```
<script>

{% autoescape false %}
var all_hotels = {{ hotels | json }};
var all_restaurants = {{ restaurants | json }};
var all_things_to_do = {{ things_to_do | json }};

{% endautoescape %}

</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation should read like this:

```
"Control auto-escaping of variable output from within your templates."

// myvar = '<foo>';
{% autoescape true %}{{ myvar }}{% endautoescape %}
// => &lt;foo&gt;
{% autoescape false %}{{ myvar }}{% endautoescape %}
// => <foo>
```

So when autoescape is `true`, it will HTML-escape variable content. I think this is the default setting for Swig.

Since you want to render JSON-variables, your code should work okay (turning off autoescaping to prevent HTML-escaping of the JSON content). Alternatively, you could use the [`safe`](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#safe) filter:

```
var all_hotels = {{ hotels | safe | json }};
var all_restaurants = {{ restaurants | safe | json }};
...
```

Comment: Ive been looking for hours how to prevent swig from doing that. Thank you!!